# Issues with Google Maps in web application

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm working on a personal project. It is a form, that allows a user to select a store based off their location. For testing purposes, the fields are set to read only.

Here it is: https://codepen.io/brettdavis4/pen/wraNJV

Here are the issues:

The map doesn't display when it is first clicked. It displays if I adjust the screen size. I can't tell if the issue is because it is in codepen.

If I click to close the map and I go to reopen, the infowindows are broken. I know what part of the problem is. I'm initializing the form after the button click and not the page load. I tried to do it off page load, but it wasn't picking up the lat/long of the address.

I'm trying to write functions for the in the infowindows and I'm not having any luck. I'm looking for suggestions on this.

Here is some of the code from the project:

```
$('#btnClosestBB').click(function(event){
  //$('#map-canvas').remove();  
  //$("<div/>").attr('id','map-canvas').appendTo('body');    

  event.preventDefault();
  $('#myModal').modal('show');  

  initialize();
});

var address = document.getElementById('address').value + ', ' + document.getElementById('city').value + ', ' + document.getElementById('state').value + ' ' + document.getElementById('zip').value;

var stores = [
    {
        name: 'Greenwood Best Buy',
        phone: '317-555-1000',
        long: -86.119458,
        lat: 39.629789,
        id: 1
    },
    {
        name: 'Eastside Best Buy',
        phone: '317-555-1000',
        long: -85.992033,
        lat: 39.773182,
        id: 2
    },
    {
        name: 'Castleton Best Buy',
        phone: '317-555-1000',
        long: -86.069270,
        lat: 39.906005,
        id: 3
    },
    {
        name: 'Carmel Best Buy',
        phone: '317-555-1000',
        long: -86.230302,
        lat: 39.934572,
        id: 4
    },
    {
        name: 'North Carmel Best Buy',
        phone: '317-555-1000',
        long: -86.129277,
        lat: 40.000897,
        id: 5
    },
    {
        name: 'Avon Best Buy',
        phone: '317-555-1000',
        long: -86.339541,
        lat: 39.764612,
        id: 6
    },
    {
        name: 'Lafayette Rd. Best Buy',
        phone: '317-555-1000',
        long: -86.245499,
        lat: 39.839805,
        id: 7
    }
];


function showResult(result) {
    document.getElementById('latitude').value = result.geometry.location.lat();
    document.getElementById('longitude').value = result.geometry.location.lng();
}

function getLatitudeLongitude(callback, address) {
    // Initialize the Geocoder
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    if (geocoder) {
        geocoder.geocode({
            'address': address
        }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
               callback(results[0]);   
            }
        });
    }    
}

function initialize() {
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(document.getElementById('latitude').value, document.getElementById('longitude').value);

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
          zoom: 12,
          center: center
    });

    var contentString = document.getElementById('name').value,
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: contentString}),
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: center, map: map, icon: 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png'});
    marker.addListener('click', function(){
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
    infowindow.open(map,marker);  

    for (var i = 0; i < stores.length; i++) {
      var contentString2 = stores[i].name + '<br/><a href="#" class="mapclick" data-value="test">Select Store</a>';
      infowindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: contentString2}),
      marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(stores[i].lat, stores[i].long), map: map, icon: 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png'});
      /*marker2.addListener('click', function(){
        infowindow2.open(map, marker2);
      });*/
      infowindow2.open(map,marker2); 
    }  
}

$('a.mapclick').click(function(event){
  event.stop();  
  console.log('test..');
});

//convert address to lat/long
getLatitudeLongitude(showResult, address);
```

Thanks!

Comment: I dont think you are providing a Google Maps API key. You can clearly see the warning in the console. Maybe try adding the key.

Comment: I think that would fix the first issue.  I'm not sure if that would address the other issues.

Comment: I have added an api key and it looks like I'm still having an issue.

Comment: You should initialise the map (call the `initialize` function) only once after the google maps library is loaded. You can do that by adding a `callback=functionName` parameter to the google maps library URL.

Comment: Do you know how I can load the lat and longitude from the address before I call the initialize function?

Comment: Using `$('#myModal').on("shown.bs.modal", initialize)` seems to fix all the problems. What this does is to call the `initialize` function only after the modal is shown. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NaNRVM

Comment: Thanks a bunch!  That solved the first 2 issues.  I'm trying to apply onclick events to the "Select Store" link in the infowindow.  I was trying to pass in a function and a link and I also tried it with jquery and didn't have any luck.

Comment: This might help. [Google Map simple click event](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-simple)

Comment: I'm trying to click on a link inside an info window.

Comment: For your infowindow issue: [documentation on Infowindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple). If you need more help you can post another question with an updated sample code. :)